# Difficulties with the definition of extension

Tags: field-theory

Suppose we have two fields $E$ and $F$ such that $F\subset E$. Then we call $E$ an extension of $F$.

By $"\subset"$ I understand the set-theoretical inclusion.

But couple days ago when I was reading the following theorem: If $k$ is a field and $p(X)\in k[X]$ is irreducible polynomial then there exists an extension $E$ of $k$ such that $E$ contains a root of $p(x)$.

And the field $E= k[X]/(p(X))$ but it does not contain $k$ as a subset. I know that we can form embedding (injective homomorphism) of $k$ into $E$ **OR** identify $k$ with subfield of $E$. But anyway to be honest we have no $k\subset E$, right?

I would be very grateful can anyone in detail explain this moment to me, please! Because I have very big difficulties and I've asked many people to explain this to me but maybe I am dumb and cannot understand this properly. Maybe somebody from MSE can do this.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Could you give a more detailed answer, please? Some moments of your comments seems quite unclear :(

Comment: I just know how rationals can be constructed from integers :( unfortunately i am not familiar with this :(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Yes I took a look at links but still have difficulties. Cannot convince myself. Also one more question: if $E$ is an extension of a field $k$ (suppose that $k$ is not a subset of $E$!). Then many in books it is written then we can consider $E$ as an $k$-vector space. Why? If $k$ is not a subset of $E$ how can we multiply elements of $E$ to "scalars" from $k$? This sounds pointless because they have different nature. Do you see that there some troubles in the definition of an extension? Would be very grateful for detailed answer. Examples would be great!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I would be very greatful for help!

Answer (score 1):

In reality a field extension $F$ of $K$ is just a given (injective) homomorphism of fields $K \to F$. Thus you can identify $K$ with a subfield of $F$, but for $F$ to be an extension of $K$, $K$ need not necessarily be defined as a subset of $F$, you just have to find an embedding of $K$ into $F$.

Therefore, if $K[X]$ is the ring of polynomials and $P$ is an irreducible polynomial, then $F:= K[X]/(P)$ is a field, and you can find an obvious embedding of $K$ into $F$ by sending an element $x \in K$ to the constant polynomial $x$ modulo $P$. Therefore $F$ is an extension of $K$.

I hope this answers your question.